# Xamarin, disable cancel during installation of apk

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I launch programmatically apk file and install it. How to catch 'Cancel' button press event during installation of apk update? Or is it to possible to disable 'Cancel' button?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. This popup is shown by the android system to make sure if the user want to install this application or not. And the cancel button's clicked event should also be dealt with by the system.

The third party app has no permission to access it or disable it to prevent third-party apps from being forced to install. But you can also post an issue on the google developers' community.